# Silly Example But Type Errors?

Tags: python, class, error-handling

```
class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self,run,fast):
        self.run=run
        self.fast=fast

    def skip(self,to,store):
        return 'Cat'

class Dog(Cat):
    def __init_(self,run, fast,tongue):
        Cat.__init__(self,run,fast)
        self.tongue=tongue

    def skip(self,to,store,happier):
        return 'Doggy'
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self,velocity):
        self.velocity=velocity

"""
velocity is a list of speeds or something. But it can 
be from dogs or cats. Fast is a single number
"""
class Owner(Parent):
    def __init__(self,smile):
        Parent.__init__(self,velocity)
        self.smile=smile
        self.jumper=[]

    def update(self):
        # velocity is a list of instances of cats and dog
        for number in self.velocity:
            if isinstance(number,Dog):
                number.skip(to,store,happier)
                self.jumper.append(number)
            if isinstance(number,Cat):
                 number.skip(to,store)
                self.jumper.append(number)
```

The problem that keeps arises is say i go to that first if statement in the if instance update method, it keeps giving me a type error, where it is saying I only need to arguments for skip and not three. Yet I know because it is going in the block the instance I must have is dog, which needs three arguments. Why is this type error keep arising?

Comment: wait, what are you inputting into run?

Comment: run could be like this:

Comment: you're probably getting an error because Owner has no attribute run to begin with

Comment: also, whats your stacktrace? As it appears, you should be getting an AttributeError

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shown us the actual error message you're getting, but I'm going to assume that you're misinterpreting it and it's actually saying that you're passing only *two* arguments to a method that expects *three*.  Specifically, I expect that the problem is not with this code block:

```
if isinstance(number,Dog):
    number.skip(to,store,happier)
    self.jumper.append(number)
```

But with the one right after it:

```
if isinstance(number,Cat):
    number.skip(to,store)
    self.jumper.append(number)
```

Because `Dog` is a subclass of `Cat`, any instance of `Dog` is also an instance of `Cat`.  Thus, if `number` is a `Dog`, the first block of code will run successfully, and then, because you're using `if` instead of `elif`, the second block of code will try to execute, and Python will try to call `.skip(to, store)` on the `Dog`, which doesn't work, because `Dog`'s `skip` expects three arguments.

It's not clear from this contrived example what you want to do in the first place, but I suspect that the best solution to your problem is to simply change the second `if` to an `elif` so that `Dog`s won't be treated as non-`Dog` `Cat`s.

Answer (score 0):

What you've got here is a derived class which overrides a base class method with a different signature (formal parameter list).  You can read some about this here:

[Python: Can subclasses overload inherited methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398666/python-can-subclasses-overload-inherited-methods)

Perhaps you should not use the same method name in both classes, since the two methods aren't really interchangeable.  Or you could make them interchangeable by taking extra arguments as `*args` or `**kwargs`, not needing those extra arguments in the base class, but using them in the derived.  Something like this:

```
class Cat(object):
    def skip(self,to,store,*args):
        return 'Cat'

class Dog(Cat):
    def skip(self,to,store,happier):
        return 'Doggy'
```

Now either class can have its method called with three arguments (plus self).